# Can a moderator vote twice on a single post?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

I have raised a concern in the past that some of our moderators use double votes in their favor. Someone probably @celeb corrected me that it is not even possible. I want to clarify that.

Example: A user asks a question. Moderator "A" down votes it right away. Then moderator "A"  uses his moderator privilege and closes the question altogether. To me this seem like double voting. Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Describing 'downvote + close vote' as 'voting twice' seems quite strange and is likely to confuse folk reading your question - it's like saying 'being able to vote for House and Senate is unfair double voting', but those two votes are for *different things*.

Anyway, yes it is possible to downvote and VtC (vote to close). No it is not just possible for moderators, anyone can do it once they have [the required rep](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: Of course I can cast a down vote + a close vote as I have privileges. I have seen moderators so the same which I think it unethical. they -1 first and then go ahead and close the question. User gets an impression that someone -1ed it and then a mod closed the question. But the fact may be it was the mod who casted both the votes.

Comment: @muslim1, 1. it's not called double voting so please don't call out so as it's very confusing. 2. No, it's not unethical to down vote and vote to close, it is normal on SE.

Comment: @Kaveh no this is unethical. Mod pretty much acts like a judge when he closes a question/etc using mod powers. Think about this. A judge scolds you and then gives you punishment. Makes sense?

Comment: @muslim1, you can have your opinion but please understand it is not shared by us and millions of other SE users who don't find it problematic at all. Anyway, that is part of the software and we cannot change it, no point in discussing it here. It is network wide request, if you want to change it I think you should submit a feature-request on [meta.SE] (I think it will almost surely get rejected, but I think it will be a good experience for you to see how such requests are perceived by other SE users).

Comment: @Kaveh no I am not interesting in changing anything. It is just ethical issue to me. May be I am wrong. I am not pushing for anything.

Comment: @muslim1, OK, then please don't bring it up again on this meta and get used to the fact that it is the way things work on SE sites.

Comment: @muslim1 you are wrong I think. It's just not that big a deal - neither you nor the OP ever knows what way any user voted unless they say so anyway, and if the single DV the moderator might cast is out of sync with the community, their votes will massively outweigh his and they can even reopen the question.

Comment: Thanks for advising @Kaveh. I will refrain from bring it up again on meta. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JackDouglas people see me as anti-moderators here perhaps so they start to give me advice, don't bring this up again etc etc. Anyways I have seen question closed by moderator, then reopened by community, closed against by the same moderator. Don't want to bother you guys about this. Probably you ppl will get offended so I will just not discuss. Thx

Comment: @muslim1 show me a link (like [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/posts/17339/revisions)) or it didn't happen.

Comment: @JackDouglas it did happen. Others can testify. Have to dig in for the link. Happened months ago. I don't even remember the topic. But what if you see the link? No body complains about such things here except me.

Comment: Which 'others' can testify - how can I ask them unless you name them. I'm not saying it didn't happen but why should I or anyone else take your word for it on the internet - if you care enough find the link, and in the meantime here's one for you: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=moderator it seems to be untrue to say "No body complains about such things here except me", don't you agree? unless you've talking to yourself on this thread and not someone called @Kaveh

Comment: It seems to me that some complaints are constructive and others are not - look at the votes in that list to get an idea of which are which!

Comment: What's so wrong with down-voting and voting to close if there is a legitimate reasons for closing the question?! There's really nothing wrong with that however if you disagree with the mod decision you can simply bring it on meta and make your case. So decisions can not be judged on their face. It's the underlying reasons and intentions that must be taken into account.